# Why are my values not matching my wordpress options?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on the settings page for a plugin I am writing.  There is a form field that let's the user select which currency symbol they want to use when displaying prices.  I have created a function that easily displays select menus and determines which option should be selected based on the option stored in the database.  For some reason, nothing is being selected in the select menu of the form.

[image: option value]

This is the plugin code for this page...

```
<?php
function hc_options() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>HeadChef Settings</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Currency Format</th>
        <td>
            <?php echo select_menu('currency_format', array('1' => '$12.50', '2' => '$12,50'), esc_attr( get_option('currency_format'))); ?>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Currency Character</th>
        <td><?php
        $options = array(
            htmlspecialchars('&#186;') => '&#186; Generic',
            htmlspecialchars('&#36;') => '&#36; Dollar',
            htmlspecialchars('&#163;') => '&#163; Pound',
            htmlspecialchars('&#165;') => '&#165; Yen',
            htmlspecialchars('&#128;') => '&#128; Euro',
            htmlspecialchars('&#8369;') => '&#8369; Peso'
            ); 
        echo select_menu('currency_prefix', $options, htmlspecialchars(esc_attr(get_option('currency_prefix')))); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Currency Suffix <br><small>(I.E. USD... Leave blank to disable.)</small></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="currency_suffix" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('currency_suffix') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <th scope="row">Enable Dish Ratings</th>
        <td>
            <fieldset><?php echo radio_buttons('Enable Dish Ratings', 'enable_dish_ratings', array('1' => 'Yes', '2' => 'No'), esc_attr(get_option('enable_dish_ratings'))); ?>
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th scope="row">Description Character Limit <small>Leave blank for no limit</small></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="description_char_limit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('description_char_limit') ); ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } 
function select_menu($title, $options, $selected){

    $output = '<select name="'.$title.'">\r\n';

    if(count($options) > 0){

        foreach($options as $val => $label){

            $output .= '<option value="'.$val.'"';
            if($val == $selected){

                $output .= ' SELECTED';

            }
            $output .= '>'.$label."</option>\r\n";

        }

    }

    $output .= "</select>\r\n";

    return $output;

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the esc_attr function was screwing with it and the currency_prefix option was parsed as `&#036;` instead of `&#36;`.

Comment: Yes in HTML terms they are.  But when you compare the values in PHP, they are not the same.

Comment: nowhere in the code you gave are you comparing the two. don't downvote people for giving you legitimate info when you're the one who didn't ask the question clearly.